# How to prevent additional JFrames when that class is being extended by other classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making a buzzlike game in which the main problem is when the class, where i create the JFrame and panels, is being extended from other classes because by creating an item of that class, i have +1 frame. So i have additional frames i dont want. The code is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameStart game;
    game = new GameStart();
    game.gReady();
}

public class GameStart extends JFrame{

protected JPanel panel, headline;
protected BorderLayout border;
protected GridLayout grid, head;
protected JLabel question;
protected JButton[] button;
protected JLabel label;
protected JLabel empty;

public GameStart(){
    setSize(500,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    panel = new JPanel();
    headline = new JPanel();

    question = new JLabel();

    button = new JButton[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        button[i] = new JButton();
        panel.add(button[i]);
    }

    label = new JLabel();
    empty = new JLabel();

    border = new BorderLayout();

    grid = new GridLayout(4,1);
    head = new GridLayout(1,0);

    headline.add(question);
    headline.setLayout(head);

    setLayout(border);
    panel.setLayout(grid);

    add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(headline, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    panel.setVisible(true);
    headline.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

This is the problematic class as i tried to find out

```
public void gReady(){
    GameMenu game;
    game = new GameMenu();
    game.languageMenu();
}
```

The languageMenu() can even be empty but GameMenu() needs to extend GameStart(). Is there any way to prevent other "child" classes from creating extra frames?

```
public class GameMenu extends GameStart {
    public GameMenu(){}
    public void languageMenu(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you call setVisable in the constructor of GameStart so it pops up when you create it.
Remove it from there and call it only when you want to show that JFrame.

Also, why do you extend it with GameMenu? just create different JFrame

Comment: I want the JFrame to be able to change from other classes so i need it to be entended by them. Thank you for the help :)